# Generating interop wrapper classes throws error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6, interop

When generating interop wrapper classes in visual studio 10 the tool throws the following error:
Interopform wrapper class generator: Error creating interopForm Wrapper Classes for Project xxx

Error list is empty

where can I start to search for the source of the Error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was: moving the interopform into a folder.
Interopforms can only be in the root of the containing project to generate a wrapper class.